# Unable to open Citrix hosted application

Tags: citrix, web-application

I would like to check with you regarding an issue, one of our user is facing while trying to the access the hosted application on Citrix Xenapp website.

In detail.

We have checked with the user and observed that user is successfully able to login to Citrix Xenapp website. And user is able to see the hosted application listed. However, for some reason user is unable to open any hosted application. Once she tries to open the application, like usual .ICA file is been downloaded and generally start loading the application. But after a while the .ICA session, fails loading the application and exits itself without ever specifying any error.

Could anyone plse let me know how to resolve this issue